# On DBConnections reuse

Tags: java, database-connection

**Today:**

I continue to work on an application, which, constantly creates and closes a LOT of (sql) connections to the same (Oracle) database, using the same credentials running very basic selects, updates and inserts.

Currently, a `singleton CustomConnectionManager` checks in its pool to see if any `CustomConnector`s are available to be given out. Once given out they may be closed by the client. Upon `close()` the underlying `SQLConnection` (created and maintained by the `CustomConnector`) is also closed. If `CustomConnector` is unavailable, new `CustomConnector` is created.

The good thing about this is that ultimately `SQLConnection` remains closed after each use, however, very little reuse is going on as the value lies in `SQLConnection` not in `CustomConnector`.

Since all users of the system will connect to the same database, the same single connection may be used to accommodate all requests. Original solution that created new Connectors upon each request seems very wasteful.

**Proposed:**

`singleton CustomConnectionManager` will maintain 2 queues:

- a queue of available `CustomConnector`, each of which will maintain it's own `SQLConnection` and
- a queue of `inUse` `CustomConnector`s. Upon request new `CustomConnector` will be created and given out.

Client interaction only happens with the `singleton CustomConnectionManager`.

When new connection is needed, manager creates it, gives it out to client and places it in `inUse` queue. When client is done using the connection, instead of closing it, client will `.markConnectorAvailable()`, which would put it back into the `availableConnectors` queue ( Client will no longer be able to control underlying SQLConnection)

**Question 1: What do you think? Will this work? Is there an existing solution that already does this well?**

**Question 2: If proposed approach is not a complete waste, what is a good point for `CustomConnector`'s to close it's SQLConnections?**

Comment: afaik ojdbc contains connection pool for reusing connections

Answer (score 0):

That's connection pooling. ADO.Net's kills them after no use in a set time (can be set in the connectionstring, (default is two minutes as I remember.).